# Problemas com desenhar múltiplas meshes WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

Estou fazendo um cubo mágico usando WebGL 2, até aí tudo certo, fiz umas classes pra fazer contas com matrizes, outras pra cuidar de shaders e etc. Mas quando eu fui desenhar o cubo de fato ele apenas usa a textura do ultimo cubo que é desenhado na tela
[image: Cubo mágico de forma bugada]
O código que desenha o objeto e a que prepara o VAO.

```
Mesh.prototype.prepara = function() {
    gl.bindVertexArray(this.VAO);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.VBO);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(this.textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 0, 0);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.EBO);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(this.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);
};
Mesh.prototype.bind = function() {
    gl.bindVertexArray(this.VAO);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.texturas.length; i++)
        this.texturas[i].bind();
};
Mesh.prototype.draw = function(shader) {
    this.bind();

    for (let i = 0; i < this.texturas.length; i++)
        shader.setInt("texture", this.texturas[i].layer);
    shader.setMat4("transform", this.transform);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, this.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
};
```

O que me deixa confuso é que se na função draw eu utilizar o prepara() invés do bind() o resultado gerado é esse (o esperado diga-se por sinal):
[image: O Cubo funcionando]

Alguém sabe me dizer o por que disso? E como resolver? Se tiverem mais alguma duvida sobre o meu código segue o link para o meu repositório no github:
[Repositório do Github](https://github.com/Evaghetti/Rubik-s-Cube)

(Já peço perdão por algum erro bobo meu no código, é o primeiro projeto que faço com OpenGL/WebGL).

EDIT: Esqueci de mencionar, se no código do bind eu deixar assim

```
Mesh.prototype.bind = function() {
    gl.bindVertexArray(this.VAO);
};
```

O código como deveria, mas até onde eu saiba para as texturas funcionarem é preciso "bindar" elas tbm, por que isso funciona?

Comment: já tentou colocar as linhas  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0); e gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1); no metodo bind?

Comment: Já, mesmo resultado